# Pack URI syntax in User Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a very simple project where are all files are within the same solution. Getting this weird issue when trying to reference resources ***in a user control*** specifically. The same pack uri syntax works perfectly well in MainWindow.xaml but when used in user control is giving an error.

Here is my files folder structure:

[image]

Here is my Mainwindow.xaml screenshot:

[image]

SummaryView.xaml (UserControl) screenshot:

[image]

Comment: tried it.. working fine at my end.. is it giving the compile time error or runtime exception?

Comment: Compile Time error. Here is the sample solution uploaded - https://github.com/pratikrshah/ResourceIssueSampleSolution

Comment: Nit - or can you upload your sample code somewhere - so I can see any differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing out the name of the assembly explicitly:

```
"pack://application:,,,/FIBRE_Reporting;component/Resources/Brushes.xaml"
```

Comment: Fuzhou - that worked beautifully. I knew this option but didnt try since thought everything was within the same assembly. But it definitely works